# Duplicate Management in Lightning - Matching Rules vs Duplicate Rules

Tags: lightning-experience, duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

In Salesforce Classic experience, we can manually search for duplicate records and pick and choose which ones we want to merge. In Lightning, however, this is not possible, and only records identified in the "Potential Duplicates" page component can be merged manually.

The documentation is unclear in my mind on how the combination of matching rules and duplicate rules drive what records appear as "potential duplicates". What I'd like to do is create some rules that don't warn or prevent a user from creating or updating potential duplicates, but cast a wider net in terms of identifying potential duplicates so that a user can review manually. Is this best addressed through matching rules, duplicate rules, or a combination of both?

Answer (score 2):

Matching rule is the criteria that identifies a record as a duplicate record

Duplicate rule is the criteria that decides what needs to be done when a duplicate record is found.

Matchig Rule and Duplicate Rule work hand in hand.

**To address your use case -** 'What I'd like to do is create some rules that don't warn or prevent a user from creating or updating potential duplicates, but cast a wider net in terms of identifying potential duplicates so that a user can review manually. Is this best addressed through matching rules, duplicate rules, or a combination of both?'

**Solution -**

1. Create a Matching rule that identifies records as duplicates.
2. Create a duplicate rule and select appropriate check boxes to
   either warn or prevent a user from creating a potential duplicate
3. (nice to have): Drag the standard Potential Duplicate
   lightning component on the page layout for users to review and merge
   the duplicates (if they have the permission to merge records)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Rules and Matching Rules work together to show potential duplicates. You need one of each (minimum) to get any results. What you're going to need depends on what you mean by "wider net". It's possible you might need two of each, or possibly just one Matching Rule with two different Duplicate Rules but with different filters.

For example, you might choose to match on Account Name and State, but one Duplicate Rule only blocks accounts that have a status of Active, while the other matches all accounts regardless of status. Note that the first rule that triggers (e.g. is active, matches, and meets all criteria) will be used, so the least restrictive rule should be ordered last.

Even if no warning/error is generated, as long as the Duplicate Rule is triggered, those will indicate Potential Duplicates on the Record Detail page.